# Recursive version of listToArray function

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I'm quite new in Javascript. Currently I'm reading Eloquent Javascript by Marijn Haverbeke and I try to write a function that produces array from a list. There's a quite easy way to do that by loop:

```js
function listToArray(list) {
  let array = [];
  for (let node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
    array.push(node.value);
  }
  return array;
}
```

However I would like to write this in recursive way. I tried to put it like this:

List:

```js
{
  value: 1,
  rest: {
    value: 2,
    rest: {
      value: 3,
      rest: null
    }
  }
}
```

Function:

```js
function recursiveNth(list) {
  let array = [];
  if (list.rest == null) {
    array.push(list.value);
    return array;
  } else {
    array.push(list.value);
    return recursiveNth(list.rest);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[3]
```

Comment: You could handover the `array` as a parameter to `recursiveNth`. Otherwise you loose state on every invocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that every time you recurse you are creating a *new* array and then pushing into that *new* array, however, you never add onto these arrays with your further recursive calls. So, once you eventually meet your base-case and `return array` you return `[3]` to the caller of your function, which is `recursiveNth(list.rest);` in `return recursiveNth(list.rest);`. This then evaluates to `return [3]`. This cycle continues up until the original caller of your `recursiveNth();` method, thus giving `[3]` as your result.

Instead, you can return a single array and add to that array with `.concat()` by using further subsequent calls to `recursiveNth` like so:

```js
const list = { value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: null } } };

function recursiveNth(list) {
  if (list.rest == null) {
    return [list.value];
  } else {
    return [list.value].concat(recursiveNth(list.rest));
  }
}

console.log(recursiveNth(list));
```

Comment: Yeah you're right. My elements were pushed into new array every time. Now I can see my mistake. I'm really keen on your answer, it's simple and clear. Thank you.

Comment: The base case here should probably use `return [list.value]`, wrapping the element in an array so that single-element lists return arrays as do multiple-element ones.

Answer (score 3):

You could return either the value plus the result of the recursive call or an empty array.

The main function is to check if `list` has a [*truthy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, like an object or any value which is converted to boolean is `true` and return in this case the property `value` in an array as well the spreaded ([spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) result of the rcursive call with the `rest` property.

If you got a [*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, the opposite of *truthy*, like `undefined` or `null`, then only an empty array is returned. This is the return value after the check with the exit condition.

To visialize the parts of a recursive function, you got following parts (abstract pseudo code):

```
function r(value)
    if (exitCondition) return someValue;         // or an empty data structure
    return value + result of call of r(newValue) // this result can be another data structure
}
```

For the below approach, the exit condition is negated and if not an exit value is found it goes in with a value and the result of the recusion.

```js
function recursive(list) {
    return list
        ? [list.value, ...recursive(list.rest)]
        : [];
}

var list = { value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: null } } };

console.log(recursive(list));
```

Comment: _"I'm quite new in Javascript"_ - An answer with ES6 features but without any further explanation or a link to a good documentation or at least the name of the feature...

Comment: @Andreas: Why would that be any more true of ES6 features than of older features for a newcomer?  I now teach arrow functions before any other type and use rest/spread operators right from the beginning.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Because neither _Eloquent JavaScript_ nor the most part of beginner tutorials discuss ES6/7 or any newer stuff (tc39).

Comment: @Andreas: The current edition of *Eloquent JavaScript* uses arrow functions regularly, introduces `async-await`, describes rest and spread, explains template literals, but as I recall doesn't try to distinguish ES6 features from older ones.  Arbitrary tutorials are of course mixed, but plenty use ES6.

Comment: @Andreas I do believe that "Eloquent JavaScript" introduced arrow functions back in the second or the third chapter.

Comment: Overall it's quite interesting approach. Using ternary operator is not something I could figure out by myself (not yet, at least). I can understand the syntax but I still have some problems though. In the last case when function reaches its peak and the list is false (bc list.rest is null), function returns just "[ ]".  So if that is the last step, why the function doesn't return just "[ ]" in the end and is retuning the whole array instead?

Comment: the recusive function returns either an empty array, at the end or takes a value and the result of a further call in an array. the last function does not know the previous values nor the stored ones.